# WooCommerce API giving JSON Syntax Error on every request

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm getting a JSON Syntax Error whenever I want to send any request to my Wordpress site.

```
$woocommerce = new Client(
        $site,
        $key,
        $secret,
        [
            'wp_api'  => true,
            'version' => 'wc/v3',
            'query_string_auth' => true,
        ]
    );
    
    print_r($woocommerce->get('products'));
```

And when I run the function, I simply get:

```
Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException 
JSON ERROR: Syntax error
```

I dont know if there's a way to get more info about the error, cause it's not really explicit.

Comment: Is any line number of file specified? How have you determined it is this block of code?

Comment: Because it's the only code I run in the function I'm calling. Not a really complicated code :/ But the PHP Woocommerce library just gives a JSON syntax error without any details. It just says it comes from the call of the last line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, the problem came from the URL. Added "www" made the API call work.
No documentation about this, the error only saying JSON Syntax Error, was nice clues to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Solution : Just change default settings for permalink in wp-admin/options-permalink.php

Comment: You are a legend! I read it so many times before, but I forgot about that. Thank you!

Comment: La cambio a que cosa? Osea ¿Que hay y porque lo debemos cambiar?

Answer (score 1):

1. Timezone of POS should be same as timezone of the Woocommerce App
2. Get WooCommerce API details from, WooCommerce -> Settings -> Advance -> REST API . Enter description, select User & Provide Read/Write Permission. Click here for more info
3. Change the permalinks option to "Post Name" in WordPress permalink option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if your URL($site) has 'https://'

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same issue recently and have some feedback and notes for myself. I started experiencing this issue after setting up Firewall settings to block traffic from certain countries. Therefore, you might need to visit Cloudflare to verify this issue.

Extra tip: Remember to check the settings in

> /wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-status

if you migrate hosting to another server, check any plugin or php modules missing.